# Why is my website not responsive after using all of bootstrap 4 framework

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

So I have developed a website for a company using Bootstrap 4 as the framework. Having worked on having a responsive website from the beginning, I'm totally baffled to why there is a huge white gap down (size depends on device res) the right side for all devices.

Even removing parts of the code which I thought was the issue (the navbar). Still no luck, after removing each element of the website to try and determine what was causing the issue. No luck

I have uploaded the site to one of my web servers at **[www.adameastwood.co.uk/eg/index.html](https://www.adameastwood.co.uk/eg/index.html)**
Ignore the slow response time, I was given very high res images and still have not sorted the caching issue.

HTML of the navbar and header:

```
  <!-- Navigation Look into as responsive is broken -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top" id="mainNav">
    <div class="container">
      <img class=" js-scroll-trigger img-fluid paddingLogo" src="img/logo.png" href="#page-top"></img>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav text-uppercase ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#About">Warum PPG</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#Advantages">Vorteile & Merkmale</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#Purchase">Kaufen</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Kontakt</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- Header -->
  <header class="masthead mainImg">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="intro-text">
        <div class="intro-heading ">Willkommen bei</div>
        <div class="intro-lead-in">PowerPerformance Gloves</div>
        <!-- <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xl text-uppercase js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">Tell Me More</a> -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
```

I dont believe the footer or header is the source of the problem but its a starting point. Thank you for any help :)

Image of the issue 
[Iphone X res, white bar on right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBsQX.png)

Comment: Can you please post the screenshot of the huge gap?

Comment: I can't see no white gap on when browsing www.adameastwood.co.uk/eg/index.html

Comment: @ManojKuma i have posted a screenshot, hopefully you can see the issue.

Comment: @wenzzzel Ive just edited the post with a screenshot showing the white gap :)

Comment: You question is misleading, as you website is actually behaving responsive properly. You issue is this additional space but not responsive design actually.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the contact-section is causing the white gap. The headline is to wide. You can reduce its length, font-size or apply ellipsis overflow on it.

Try this:

```
#contact .section-heading {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

or this:

```
#contact .section-heading {
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

and you will see the white gap on the right side should not be there anymore.

Comment: Ive tried that but the still is a white gap to the side. It is sometimes hidden, you have to drag the screen to the right to see it.